# JSONObject Serialization

Tags: android

Hello All is there any method to serialize JSONObject having required request data for hitting any web service. I have read about Jackson, Gson library but could not find a way to do that because I have to serialize JSONObject not Java Object.

I am new to android development and not being able to figure out how this can be done.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize the `String` reppresenting the `JSONObject` .

the `toString()` implementation of `JSONObject` returns what you need. [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#toString%28%29) the doc